# Grunt: How to correctly setup .html file for mocha testing?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

I am new to **grunt** and **tests** and currently I have setup like this:
**Grunt** running tasks after which I have **build** folder where I have my compiled **index.html** and all his resources (**css**, **js**, **images**)
Now I want to run tests using **grunt-mocha-phantomjs** and it needs additions to my **index.html** like:

`<link href="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Inside **head** tag and:

`<div id="mocha"></div>`
`<script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`
`<script src="../node_modules/chai/chai.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">`
`mocha.ui('bdd');`
`expect = chai.expect;`
`</script>`
`<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">`
`mocha.run();`
`</script>`

Inside **body** tag.

I want to be able to open that modified **index.html** in web-browser too. (I have setup **apache** for it and [example test](https://github.com/jdcataldo/grunt-mocha-phantomjs/tree/master/test) works great both in **grunt** and web-browser)
So I am planning using task **grunt-contrib-copy** to copy all files from my **build** directory to **test** directory and add those lines to **index.html** and then launch **mocha_phantomjs** task.

- Is this correct way to do it?
- Which **NpmTask** can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about "**Is this correct way to do it?**" part but I solved it.
I used **grunt-html-build** and its [Removing parts](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build/wiki/Removing-parts) feature.
Removing phantom's code for **build** folder, and keep it for **testing** folder.
It works great.